# How to disable domain proxy redirect on a subdomain with nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, dns

I have three files on my nginx conf.d -

```
example.com 
www.example.com
other.example.com
```

example.com is my preferred domain and is proxy passing a nodejs app.

example.com has the following config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

www.example.com has the following config:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

In other.example.com I have the following config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name other.example.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    root /opt/other;
    index index.html;
}
```

But when I go to other.example.com I get the same result as www.example.com and example.com

Any thoughts how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Did you enable the other.example.com configuration?

Comment: How so? I guess that everything I put inside conf.d will be executed by nginx on service start...(and that config is inside conf.d)

Comment: when you go to `other.example.com`, does your URL stay the same or changes to `example.com`?

Comment: also please show your `example.com` config, or at least your `server_name` directive

Comment: @Curious when I go to other.example.com the content is the same as example.com and the link stays unchanged (other.example.com). Already updated the question with the example.com config.

Comment: by default Nginx loads only `.conf` files from `conf.d` directory. try to rename `other.example.com` to `other.example.com.conf`

Comment: That solved! Apparently in a noobly fashion I forgot to add that only to the other.example.com config file.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved.

I forgot to name other.example.com file with the .conf extension.

thanks to @Curious